# How can I politely ask my money back?

Tags: friends, money, europe, trust

I lent some money to a friend two months ago, in order to help him start his own job. He asked me if I could give him 350€ to pay some workers that had done some wall painting at his place, and that he was was going to return the money without saying when.

Now, after 2 months, he still didn't give me back my money, and he didn't even contact me. I'm very disappointed about the fact that he asked me easily about the money and that he was in difficult financial situation.

As a good a friend as I am, I helped him, but recently, I saw some photos in his social network where he was enjoying a trip in a foreign European country and I felt like an idiot.

I want my money back, but I'm worried that if I call him, I'm going to get mad and brake our friendship and I don't want that to happen. 
I'm thinking to send him a text message and ask him to give me the money whenever he is ready.

I want to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's my personal belief that it's best to handle such things in person, or at least via phone call.  That said, text can be made to work.

I'll caution you though ... if you tell him to pay you back "when he's ready", that's the same situation you're already in.  It's better if you lean just a trifle harder, perhaps, "Hey X, when can you slide that 350€ back my way?  I've got [something true] expenses coming up..."

In other words, you're asking him to commit to a date.  Which is what you need, because "whenever" tends to edge into "never".

Don't worry about breaking the friendship.  If he's truly your friend, he'll understand your quite gentle prompting, and work something out with you.